# Get cart id on prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I'm trying to get the current cart id from prestashop with:

```
$cookie->id_cart;
```

But it's blank until I add a product in the cart.

Is there any option to create that cart so I can get the id?

Thanks.

Comment: cart id only gets generated once you add a product in your cart... without that there is no cart id... can you tell what is the purpose of getting the cart id?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved it, I just needed to create before the cart id.

```
if (is_null($context->cart->id)) {

     $context->cart->add();

     $context->cookie->__set('id_cart', $context->cart->id);
}
```

So I can now add products programmatically in my current cart.